# Samsung Galaxy S6 not connecting to Windows 10 - not even detecting the device

Tags: samsung, windows, samsung-galaxy-s-6

Can some one help me to identify the root cause of this issue? I tried almost every available solution online and nothing work around.

Installed smart switch
change 2 cables
Put on USB debugging mode change to MTP settings doesn't works

Cables only charging my phone.

Laptop: Nitro 7 (I use port 2.0 for connection that doesn't works too)

Comment: If you have replaced every hardware component outside of the phone (USB cable, PC, ..) and the phone software has not been changed it may be a defect USB port. Such a defect is pretty common: when the USB plug is inserted every jiggle on the plug puts a strong force on the soldering points that connect the USB port to the mainboard. If too often a too high force is applied the soldering point can break and the USB port is getting lose.